# Read file content from NFS using Java

Tags: java, nfs, nfsclient

I'm trying to read file from NFS using Java.

I'm try to use https://github.com/raisercostin/yanfs with the following code:

```
        XFile xf = new XFile("nfs://192.168.1.183/nfs-share-folder/myfile.zip");
        nfsXFileExtensionAccessor nfsx =
        (nfsXFileExtensionAccessor)xf.getExtensionAccessor();

        // login
        nfsx.loginPCNFSD("mynfssrv", "evyatarel", "mypassword")) {

       //Check for permission
        if (xf.canRead())
             System.out.println("Read permission OK");
        else
             System.out.println("No Read permission");

        //How to read the file content?
```

I have permission to read the file but how can I get the file content?

Any suggestions/Another methods to read files from NFS?

Thanks!